# How to specify to match more than one character inside regex sqaure brackets?

Tags: regex, regex-group

Given a user input string, I need to find if it end with one of the following - .com, .net , .edu., html  etc.

Is there any way to do this with the regex square brackets?

I tried $[.com|.net|.html] and $[(.com)(.net)(.html)] but both don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a capture group.

```
(\.com|\.net|\.html)
```

This will match either one of the values. You can add additional values by appending another pipe inside the parenthesis and placing the new value after the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
\.com$|\.net$|\.edu$
```

or

```
(\.com|\.net|\.edu)$
```